# super class constructor in custom exception in java

Tags: java, constructor, superclass

I am learning features in java including exceptions. I am writing a custom exceptions. Here is what i am doing :custom exception class:

```
 public class ServiceException extends Exception {

    private String customMessage;

    public ServiceException(String customMessage) {
        super(customMessage);
        this.customMessage = customMessage;

    }
}
```

Main class:

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Main().test();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("the exception message is " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void test() throws ServiceException {
        try {
            int i = 1 / 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This much i know:
if super class constructor  is not invoked in the custom exception class, the message set in the custom exception is not passed to the Exception class. But if i have a method **public String getMessage** in my custom exception class, even if the super is not invoked, that message is printed . Sorry  if this is a naive question. But i am failing to understand he concept. Could come one help clear the concept ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main where you are catching the error, you are basically assigning a ServiceException object to a Exception reference, i.e. assigning derived class object to base class reference, so if the derived class has overridden the method, it will get called.

the e.message() being called is from ServiceException not Exception, you are right, no data is being passed when you are not calling super, data is inside ServiceException class only and the function invoked is also from ServiceException class.

Comment: checkout dynamic polymorphism. a simple link for headstart : http://way2java.com/oops-concepts/dynamic-polymorphism/

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are supplying it. You are passing `e.getMessage()` to your constructor as the only argument, customMessage. You then pass `customMessage` to its parent's constructor that takes a `String`, `Exception(String)`. In doing so, you are giving it the message to use for `serviceExceptionInstance.getMessage()`. Instead, do not pass the `customMessage` to its parent (use `super();`, which is implied if no call to a parent constructor is given and a no-arg, parent constructor exists). Then the message will be `null` as it is not supplied.

In other words:

```
new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
```

Creates a new `ServiceException` with the message from `e`. You pass that message to `Exception`, `ServiceException`'s parent.

```
super(customMessage);
```

In doing so, you use the single argument, `String`-based constructor of `Exception`. Passing a value to that constructor implies that you want it used when callers invoke `getMessage`.  To avoid doing this, call a different parent constructor, or none at all (calling none is technically not possible, and it will implicitly do `super();` for you):

```
public ServiceException(String customMessage)
{
    this.customMessage = customMessage;
}
```

This will call `super();` for you, which means that the parent class has no message to send, and by *not* overriding `getMessage()` yourself, then it will return its default value (`null`). To be clear, `Exception` itself extends from `Throwable`, which is really the class providing this functionality, but it all stems from how you work with `Exception` as it serves as a pass-thru to `Throwable`.

Comment: I understand the process when i supply super, but what i fail to understand is when i don't supply super.Then how is the message printed from the getMessage function ?There is no data passed to the parent Exception class na ?

Comment: If don't supply super, then it does _not_ have a message to supply. It assumes _no_ message, and it defaults the value to be `null.`

Comment: yes,but if there is a method getMessage which returns string in the custom exception class, e.getMessage is not null ? is it because the getMessage in custom exception overrides the getMessage from the Exception class ?

Comment: thanks for the time pickypg i was looking for the dynamic polymorphism  feature, din't strike it till gaurav5430 explained.